# Null infinity reachable by timelike worldlines?

Tags: general-relativity, spacetime, differential-geometry, causality, topology

Usually, Penrose diagrams are marked with points and segments being named *past/future timelike infinity* $i^{-,+}$, *past/future null infinity* $\mathscr{I}^{-,+}$ and *spacelike infinity* $i^0$ -- see for example the diagram of german wikipedia's *Penrose diagram* page (figure below).

[image]
*(Source: de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Penrose-Diagramm, 23.11.2023)*

I was wondering how those notions are justified. I understand, that $i^0$ is not reachable by any timelike worldline. However, consider e.g. a timelike wordline, starting in the center and proceeding at an angle, say $40°$ to the x-axis. Such a timelike wordline reaches future null infinity $\mathscr{I}^+$. So why is it, that timelike wordlines are supposed to always end in $i^+$, when I just provided a counter example. Did I misunderstand something?

Comment: Of course it takes an infinite time to travel to spatial infinity.

Comment: But $i^+$ lies on $t=\infty$ too, doesn't it?

Comment: Yes, but your assumption that a worldline starting at the center with 40° stays 40° is incorrect, it will curve inwards like the orange worldline in these coordinates. The orange worldline looks like constant velocity, you'd need acceleration to keep a fixed angle below 45° on such a spacetimediagram. Only 45° will stay 45°. On the top and bottom of the diagram where the worldline looks as if it were moving to the left it is in fact moving to the right, as you can see on the curves of constant x.

Comment: @Yukterez They defined the worldline to be everywhere inclined at 40°, so it is. It's not a geodesic. The question isn't about geodesics.

Comment: @benrg - the statement that you have to end up in i+ can only be valid for timelike geodesics, if you accelerate all the way up to infinity so that your worldline stays at constant angle that's a different story.

Comment: @Yukterez The world line you are talking about - is it the one which starts from middle of penrose diagram? In general, all timelike curves originating from $i^-$ will end up in $i^+$.

Comment: @KP99 - the whole manifold is inside the lightcone originating at i-, so every timelike curve in the whole manifold could be traced back to i-, therefore it shouldn't really make a difference where it really originated since all possible starting positions are reachable from i-.

Comment: @Yukterez Note that the future of $\mathscr{I}^-$ is also the whole manifold just like that of $i^-$. So not every time like trajectories need to trace back to $i^-$. You can have trajectories which start from $\mathscr{I}^-$.

Comment: @KP99 - I don't mean that they must originate there, but that the could originate there or be influenced by a signal from there, since they are inside its lightcone. Since the trajectories originating at I- and those originating at i- can intercept inside of the manifold, if should't matter where they originated in the past, to calculate where a path ends up in the future you only need to know its present and future conditions. The particle might already have forgotten where it originated, all that counts is where it is right now and how it accelerates in the future.

Comment: @KP99 - a particle originating from i- could meet a particle originating from I- at housenumber t=0.5, x=0.5 and decide to join him in his flight or vice versa, there should be no bouncer at I+ or i+ that asks them where they came from.

Comment: @Yukterez Yes I agree that they are causally connected. I was originally asking about your comment to benrg "the statement ... a different story". Can you be more specific which accelerated trajectories you are talking about? Is it the one originating from $i^-$?

Comment: @KP99 - the constant 40° trajectory I'm talking about it not drawn in the diagram on Wipipedia, I'm just saying that 40°<45°, in other words v<c, and therefore a timelike curve that connects to I+, only that it's not a geodesic but accelerated since timelike geodesics of constant velocity are curved, not straight lines in those coordinates, that's all I'm saying.

Comment: @KP99 - since acceleration all the way up to infinity leads to v approaching c the timelike curves ending up in I+ are ultrarelativistic though since their speed is just an infinitesimal below the speed of light, but technically they're still timelike, just in the limit v→c, but not v=c. Of course such a worldline is unrealistic and will not occur in nature, but theoretically speaking. All realistic timelike curves will end up in i+, that is out of question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/149908/discussion-between-kp99-and-yukterez).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not necessarily true that the end points should be at $i^{\pm}$. You can have time-like curves whose end points are on $\mathscr{I}^{\pm}$. It is helpful to look at the future or past set of a given trajectory. Note that, for any point $p\in\mathbb{M}$, the future set $I^+[p]$ is same as $I^+[\gamma]$ for any time-like curve $\gamma$ with past end point at $p$. Then clearly, for any two timelike curves $\alpha$ and $\beta$ with the same past end point $p$, we have $I^+[\alpha]=I^+[\beta]=I^+[p]$. Similar argument can be said for past set. So take $p=i^-$. Then note that $I^+[i^-]=\mathbb{M}=I^-[i^+]$. This essentially implies that any time-like curve which starts from $i^-$ will end at $i^+$

Let me add the definition for future/past set: $I^{\pm}[p]$ is defined as collection of all such points (subspace of $\mathbb{M}$) which can be reached from the point $p$ by a future (for $I^+$) / past (for $I^-$) directed time-like curve

Comment: Not all timelike curves, but all timelike geodesics. To avoid i+ you'd need proper acceleration all the way, which gets your v to the limit of c.

Comment: Why just timelike geodesics and not timelike curves? The definition of chronological sets $I^{\pm}$ includes all timelike curves. Even if there is proper acceleration, the curve will reach arbitrarily close to $\mathscr{I}$ , but will have end points on $i$ only. The argument using $I^{\pm}$ is very generic as pointed out by Penrose (see section on TIPs and TIFs (pg 295 onwards) from Spinors and Spacetime Vol-II)

Comment: Could you elaborate on the implication you state (before the definition)? Doesn't the equation $I^+[i^-] = M = I^-[i^+]$ only imply that a time-like curve that starts at $i^-$ CAN have end-point $i^+$ and vice versa? Because $\mathscr{I}^+ \subset M$ and so $\mathscr{I}^+ \subset I^+[i^-]$, right? Or is the argument, that because $\mathscr{I}^+ \subset I^-[i^+]$, then one can always "extend" a curve from $\mathscr{I}^+$ to continue to $i^+$?

Comment: You might be confusing physical spacetime  with unphysical spacetime M.  is boundary of M while  is the interior of M. So   is not a part of $I^{\pm}$. Moreover $I[\alpha]=I[\beta]$ <-> p is past/end point : this statement is an if and if statement. So any time like curve which starts at i^- will end at i^+ and vice versa

Answer (score 5):

> So why is it, that timelike wordlines are supposed to always end in $i^{+}$, when I just provided a counter example. Did I misunderstand something?

You provided an example of a timelike *curve* that reaches null infinity. Arguably, such curve could not be called a *realistic* worldline. Note, that if we assume that a massive object (such as particle) travels along such curve then in order to “outrun” (some of) photons travelling in the same direction it must be approaching the speed of light and hence would gain  infinite energy from the viewpoint of an observer at origin.

So if we consider e.g. a scattering process in Minkowski spacetime with finite total energy, then worldlines of incoming massive particles originate at past timelike infinity $i^{-} $ and outgoing massive particles end up at at future timelike infinity $i^{+} $. While null infinities are for massless particles/waves.