# Allowed geodesics in Penrose diagrams for (3+1)D Minkowski spacetime with spherical polar coordinates?

Tags: general-relativity, black-holes

It is often said that all time-like geodesics are from $i^{-}$ to $i^{+}$, all space like geodesics end up with $i^{0}$, etc. The exact statement is quoted from Prof. Harvey Reall's Part III Black Holes lecture notes, pp 64. I do not repeat them here. See the Figure below for notations.

[image]

How to prove that there are no other allowed geodesics in the family defined in LHS of the figure? E.g. in the RHS of the figure, why could not the red ones and the green one exist? How to show they and others are not allowed mathematically?

Comment: Related : https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/789790/303640

Comment: Thanks. Indeed from your previous answer, all time-like geodesics starting from i- would reach i+ and they span the whole manifold (after conformal conpactification). But there are other time-like geodesics that are not in this family.

Comment: It is easy to see that your red curves outrun light.  This is not possible without acceleration.

Comment: An interesting relevant illustration is timelike geodesics reaching the speed of light at the black hole horizon, which is null and similar to the null infinity. In this case the particle is moving with a gravitational acceleration diverging at the horizon (similar to your red curves), by due to the curvature still remains on a geodesic (unlike your red curves).

Answer (score 1):

**TL;DR**: If you explicitly write down a generic geodesic in $\mathbb{R}^{1,3}$ and evaluate the Bondi coordinates $(u,v)$ over it, you find that as the affine parameter $\lambda\to \infty$ the values of $u$ and $v$ are such that the null ones end up on ${\cal I}^\pm$, the timelike ones end up on $i^\pm$ and the spacelike ones ones on $i^0$. Since this analysis encompasses *all geodesics*, a generic one must fall in one of the three categories.

**Detailed Analysis**:

The geodesic equation in Cartesian coordinates is just $$\ddot x^\mu(\lambda)=0.$$

As a result *all* geodesics are given by $$x^\mu(\lambda)=\lambda v^\mu+x_0^\mu.$$

Where $x_0,v\in \mathbb{R}^{1,3}$ are constants. The light-like ones have $v^2=0$ and the timelike ones have $v^2=-1$, while space-like ones have $v^2=1$. That said, we can now evaluate the Bondi coordinates of $x^\mu(\lambda)$. First go to spherical coordinates by defining $$t=x^0,\quad r=\sqrt{(x^1)^2+(x^2)^2+(x^3)^2},\quad z=\dfrac{x^1+ix^2}{x^3+r},\quad \bar z=\dfrac{x^1-ix^2}{x^3+r}.$$

Finally define $$u=t-r,\quad v=t+r.$$

We immediately have that $$u(\lambda)=\lambda v^0+x_0^0-\sqrt{\vec{x}_0^2+2\lambda\vec{x}_0\cdot \vec{v}+\lambda^2 \vec{v}^2},\quad v=\lambda v^0+x_0^0+\sqrt{\vec{x}_0^2+2\lambda\vec{x}_0\cdot \vec{v}+\lambda^2 \vec{v}^2}.$$

Now let us take $\lambda\to+\infty$ and try to understand where the geodesic ends. To that it will be useful to remember that in the coordinates $(u,v,z,\bar z)$ we have the following assignments:

- ${\cal I}^+$: $v\to \infty$ with $(u,z,\bar z)$ fixed;
- ${\cal I}^-$: $u\to -\infty$ with $(v,z,\bar z)$ fixed;
- $i^+$: $u\to \infty$ and $v\to \infty$ with $(z,\bar z)$ fixed;
- $i^-$: $u\to -\infty$ and $v\to -\infty$ with $(z,\bar z)$ fixed;
- $i^0$: $u\to -\infty$ and $v\to \infty$ with $(z,\bar z)$ fixed;

The large $\lambda$ expansion of $(u,v)$ along the geodesic is given by $$u(\lambda)=\lambda v^0-\lambda\|\vec{v}\|+O(1),\quad v(\lambda)=\lambda v^0+\lambda \|\vec{v}\|+O(1).$$

What we take from this? Assume $v^2=0$ so that $v$ is light-like. Then $v^0=\pm \|\vec{v}\|$. If $v^0>0$ so that the geodesic is future-directed, then we necessarily have $v^0=\|\vec{v}\|$. Then $u(\lambda)=O(1)$ and $v(\lambda) = O(\lambda)$ and hence $v(\lambda)\to \infty$. This means the geodesic asymptotes to ${\cal I}^+$: it has a finite value of $u$ and infinite value of $v$. Likewise if $v^0<0$ the geodesic is past-directed and then $v^0=-\|\vec{v}\|$ and we have the opposite, it will have $u(\lambda)\to -\infty$ and finite value of $v$.

Now take the timelike case. Then $v^2=-1$ and hence $-(v^0)^2+\vec{v}^2=-1$. We can solve for $v^0$ again to get $$v^0=\pm\sqrt{1+\vec{v}^2}.$$

Assume now that $v^0>0$ so that $v^0=\sqrt{1+\vec{v}^2}$. This time we have $$u(\lambda)=\lambda\left(\sqrt{1+\vec{v}^2}-\|\vec{v}\|\right)+O(1),\quad v(\lambda)=\lambda\left(\sqrt{1+\vec{v}^2}+\|\vec{v}\|\right)+O(1).$$

It is clear that as $\lambda\to \infty$ we have $v\to\infty$. On the other hand $$\sqrt{1+\vec{v}^2}-\|\vec{v}\|>0,\quad \forall \vec{v}\in \mathbb{R}^3.$$

Consequently as $\lambda\to \infty$ we have $u\to \infty$ as well, so the geodesic asymptotes to $i^+$.

On the other hand if $v^0<0$ we must have $v^0=-\sqrt{1+\vec{v}^2}$. Consequently we find

$$u(\lambda) = -\lambda \left(\sqrt{1+\vec{v}^2} +  \|\vec{v}\|\right)+O(1),\quad v(\lambda) = \lambda\left(-\sqrt{1+\vec{v}^2}+\|\vec{v}\|\right)+O(1),$$

so that now $u(\lambda)\to -\infty$ and $v(\lambda)\to -\infty$ as well. Consequently the geodesic asymptotes to $i^-$.

Finally take the spacelike case in which $v^2=1$. Then $\vec{v}^2=1+(v^0)^2$ and therefore $v^0 = \pm \sqrt{\vec{v}^2-1}$. In this case, for either choice of sign we will find that $u(\lambda)\to -\infty$ and $v(\lambda)\to \infty$ so that the geodesic asymptotes to $i^0$.

In conclusion: we know *all* geodesics in $\mathbb{R}^{1,3}$ to be straight-lines. We can then evaluate Bondi coordinates $(u,v,z,\bar z)$ over each of them and take the affine parameter to infinity to reach its endpoint. We then find that they all either end up on ${\cal I}^\pm$, $i^\pm$ or $i^0$ depending on whether they are null, timelike or space like. There can be no other geodesic.